# Sending variable in ResponseEntity

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a method in my controller that returns a String in JSON. It is working for string but not for a string variable. 
Below example is working :

```
ResponseEntity<String>  {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"test\" :\"This is a String\"} ", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is not working :

```
ResponseEntity<String>  {
String newStr= "hello" ;
 return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"test\" : newStr } ", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The returned string is processed as following:

```
function(response){                     

                            var json = JSON.stringify(response) ;
                            var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(json);                         
                            $('#location').val(jsonObject.test);                    
                    }
```

But location textbox is not updated.

Comment: `"{\"test\" : newStr } "` is complete as string , this will not take newStr as variable

Comment: on frontend you use angular or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one,

```
String newStr= "hello" ;
return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"test\":\"" + newStr + "\"}", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to refactor your string as :

```
String newStr= "hello" ;
return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"test\" : "+newStr+" } ", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: the correct string is being returned but not able to process it correctly. Please see updated answer.

Comment: are you trying to set value on dom element?

Comment: Yes, updating a textbox